# Format the legend-title in a matplotlib ax.twiny() plot

Tags: matplotlib, legend-properties

Believe it or not I need help with formatting the title of the legend (not the title of the plot) in a simple plot. I am plotting two series of data (X1 and X2) against Y in a twiny() plot.

I call *matplotlib.lines* to construct lines for the legend and then call *plt.legend* to construct a legend pass text strings to name/explain the lines, format that text and place the legend. I could also pass a title-string to plt.legend but I cannot format it.

The closest I have come to a solution is to create another 'artist' for the title using *.legend()set_title* and then format the title text. I assign it to a variable and call the variable in the above mentioned *plt.legend*. This does not result in an error nor does it produce the desired effect. I have no control over the placement of the title.

I have read through a number of S-O postings and answers on legend-related issues, looked at the MPL docs, various tutorial type web-pages and even taken a peak at a GIT-hub issue (#10391). Presumably the answer to my question is somewhere in there but not in a format that I have been able to successfully implement.

```
#Imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
plt.style.use('seaborn')

#Some made up data 
y = np.arange(0, 1200, 100)
x1 = (np.log(y+1))
x2 = (2.2*x1)

#Plot figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 14))
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

sy1, sy2 = 'b-', 'r-'

tp, bm = 0, 1100

red_ticks = np.arange(0, 11, 2)
ax1.plot(x1, y, sy1)
ax1.set_ylim(tp, bm)
ax1.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax1.set_ylabel('Distance (m)')
ax1.set_xlabel('Area')
ax1.set_xticks(red_ticks)

blue_ticks = np.arange(0, 22, 4)
ax2.plot(x2, y, sy2)
ax2.set_xlim(0, 20)
ax2.set_xlabel('Volume')
ax2.set_xticks(blue_ticks)
ax2.grid(False)

x1_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='blue')
x2_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='red')

leg = ax1.legend().set_title('Format Legend Title ?',
            prop = {'size': 'large', 
                    'family':'serif',
                    'style':'italic'})

plt.legend([x1_line, x2_line], ['Blue Model', 'Red Model'],
           title = leg,
           prop ={'size':12,
                'family':'serif',
                'style':'italic'},
            bbox_to_anchor = (.32, .92))
```

So what I want is a simple way to control the formatting of both the legend-title and legend-text in a single artist, and also have control over the placement of said legend.

The above code returns a "No handles with labels found to put in legend."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one single legend. You can set the title *of that legend* (not some other legend); then style it to your liking.

```
leg = ax2.legend([x1_line, x2_line], ['Blue Model', 'Red Model'],
                 prop ={'size':12, 'family':'serif', 'style':'italic'},
                 bbox_to_anchor = (.32, .92))
leg.set_title('Format Legend Title ?', prop = {'size': 24, 'family':'sans-serif'})
```

---

Unrelated, but also important: Note that you have two figures in your code. You should remove one of them.

Comment: Thank you Ernest for the solution and the tip. Happy trails!